# Euler angle to cartesian angle conversion

Tags: coordinate-systems

I need to calculate a new 2D point using a starting point and an Euler angle. But I'm having a hard time with converting the Euler angle to a cartesian angle.

I currently use Arturo Magidin's answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/9367/554081 to calculate my new point using a starting point, the slope and a distance.
Ideally, I want to insert the converted Euler angle into the current formula.

TLDR: How do I convert an Euler angle to a cartesian angle?

Comment: Euler angles are used to describe directions in 3-D, but you’re asking about 2-D points. Explain what you mean by “Euler angle” in this context.

Comment: By Euler angle I mean the "roll" of a 3d object. This roll is the direction in 3d space, but I'm looking for a way to translate this direction into an angle that is valid in the cartesian coordinate system. The reason for this is that I want to do some further calculations with this angle. Maybe I'm wrong but I would think that there would be some way to translate this.